# Is it possible for opposite-gendered Pokemon to show up in a chain?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I'm trying to catch a female Salandit, I've tried with the chains when one Pokemon calls another, but I spent like 1 or 2 hours, and not a single female appeared.

I don't know if it's possible or if they are going to keep being male again and again.

Comment: It's worth noting that Salandit only has a 12.5% chance of being female

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's possible. When I encountered a female Salandit, it called for backup a few times while I tried to catch it. Two females showed up, as well as a male.

In addition, when my friend was trying to catch one beside me, they encountered a male and had a female come as backup after a few males.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is complete possible for a Pokemon to call a Pokemon of a different gender. When the new Pokemon is called the stats, abilities, level, gender, ect don't really affect what Pokemon show up only really what Pokemon it is matters as you can get Pokemon who have different genders, moves, levels, ect.  It is also possible for the Pokemon to call a different Pokemon altogether as is seen in the first totem battle.